# Make Specific cshtml file to have Access to Functionality

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, visual-studio-2013

If I want a specific cshtml file (asp.net mvc 4) to have access to specific functionality in javascript or jquery, how should I enable to do it in Visual Studio 2013?

All cshtml file should not have access to all functionality in javascript or jquery.

Thanks!

Comment: The Visual Studio does not have anything to do with that.
In your specific `.cshtml` file include specific `.js` files you need.
For example `<script src="myscripts.js"></script>`

Comment: Where in the cshtml file when there is no <title><head></title></head><html></html><body></body>?

Comment: @HelloWorld did my answer help? Do you need further help?

Comment: @HelloWorld what happened? Any news or thoughts on the topic you started?

Answer (score 0):

In your _Layout.cshtml define new section, e.g.

```
<head>
  <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
  @RenderSection("HeadContent", false)
</head>
```

Then in your views you can use that section to specify which js/jQuery to use:

```
@model YourViewModel
@section HeadContent{
    <script type="text/javascript" src="your.js"></script>
}
```

You can also group your scripts into partial `.cshtml` and then include that in `HeadContent` using `@Html.Partial` or `@Html.RenderPartial`.